# Action button hides from notification after a while

Tags: android

I display Notification as follows:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(con)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.image)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "test", mPendingIntent);
```

I see the notification showing up with the button as expected. The problem is if I don't touch it for like 8 seconds, then it just becomes normal notification and the button is hidden.

1) How can I enforce the button to stay there?

2) When I drag the screen from above, I can't see button. How can I expand the notification? Is this some code specific problem or device specific ( Samsung S4)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to make custom notification?

Comment: May be due to **setAutoCancel()** , it happens like this.

Comment: @MohitSuthar AddAction should add the button, I shouldnt be forced to use custom notification if AddAction adds the btutton

Comment: @NigamPatro, I didn't have autocancel before and same behviour. AutoCancel will cancel the notification when you click on it anyways